# Работа с backStack и фрагментами

Tags: android, activity, android-fragment, android-navigation-drawer

Доброго времени суток!

Делаю приложение на `fragment`'ах. Меню управления - `Navigation Drawer` из коробки шаблонов `Android Studio`.

В методе `onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)`, который отвечает за работу с элементами меню `Navigation Drawer` написал следующий код

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.item_operators:
            fragment = new OpFrag();
            FRAGMENT_TAG = "opFrag";
            break;
        case R.id.item_data:
            fragment = new DFrag();
            FRAGMENT_TAG = "dFrag";
            break;
        case R.id.item_functions:
            fragment = new FFrag();
            FRAGMENT_TAG = "fFrag";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = fragManager.beginTransaction();
    fragTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, FRAGMENT_TAG);

    /** моя проверка на наличие фрагмента в стэке */
    if (fragManager.findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG) == null) {
        fragTransaction.addToBackStack(FRAGMENT_TAG);
    }
    fragTransaction.commit();
    Log.v("myLogs", "Now in BackStack " + fragManager.getBackStackEntryCount() + " fragment(s)");

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    return true;
}
```

Но все работает криво.

Мне нужно сбрасывать весь стэк при клике по одному из элементом списка меню, а так же добавлять в стэк фрагмент только один раз.

Хронология вызовов классов:

```
          ActivityMain -> MainFrag -> OFrag -> RdFrag
```

MainFrag, RdFrag (не добавлять), OFrag, DFrag, FFrag (добавлять в стэк)

Comment: для начала, вы добавляете в стек не *фрагмент*, а *транзакцию*. То есть действия для последующего отката. Кроме того, если вы не хотите что-либо добавлять в `BackStack`, просто не вызывайте метод `addToBackStack`, в чем проблема?

Comment: @metalurgus, с не добавлением проблем нет. Как добавить фрагмент, а не транзакцию ?

Comment: Никак. В бекстек добавляются транзакции

Comment: @metalurgus , хорошо. Каким методом мне сбросить весь стэк ?

Comment: Задайте отдельный вопрос, или лучше погуглите сначала. Я перевел ваш вопрос на английский, вбил в гугл, и получил ответ по второй (да, не по первой, как обычно, а по второй) ссылке

Comment: @metalurgus, я понимаю Вашу позицию, но спешу заверить, что гуглил хорошо. Без гугления  я бы не стал создавать вопрос здесь.

Comment: @web_alex, не сильно понятно чего Вы хотите, но может это поможет getFragmentManager().popBackStack(0, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

Comment: @ravikwow, это сотрет весь back stack, верно ?